# Java Spring Specification - to avoid duplicate requests

Tags: spring, jpa

I have this entity

```
@Entity
public class EntityX {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Size(max = 20)
@Column(name = "tp", length = 20)
private String tp;

@Column(name = "created_date")
private Instant createdDate;

}
```

I have multiple rows with the same tp but with createdDate different.

using `JPQL` I'm using the following query:

`select X1 from EntityX X1 LEFT JOIN EntityX X2 ON (X1.tp = X2.tp AND X1.createdDate < X2.createdDate) where X1.tp in :tps and X2.createdDate IS NULL`

I would like to know if it is possible to have the same in a org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification or multiple Specifications?

Comment: Can you state what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: How can `x1.createdDate` be smaller than `x2.createdDate` if `x2.createdDate` has to be `null`? Or did I miss something?